# try-catch does not work in my product code

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am facing issue with try-catch blocks in my product code.
Previously my code used to build against gcc 4.3.2. Now I am trying to build it against 4.9.1.
It is compiled successfully, but when I run it, all the areas where try and catch blocks are present are not working.
i.e  when there is a throw, it throws a SIGABRT (signal 6), and process is getting terminated.
What might I be missing here. Some libraries or something?

Here is some sample code I have tried in svupdate that is not working.

```
try
{
    printf("Before the std::exception");
    throw std::exception(); ---> The process gets aborted here with  ["Abort trap: 6 (core dumped)"]
    printf("After the std::exception");
}
catch (...)
{
    printf("ignoring this time"); ---> This is not being logged 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using an incompatible runtime environment?

Comment: is this on MacOS?

Comment: It is on FreeBSD

Comment: got homebrew installed? what `brew config`, `brew doctor` would report? This essentially signifies that something is wrong with your toolchain\libraries, not with your code. something is of incompatible version

Comment: You didn't compile the program with `-fno-exceptions`, did you?

Comment: 4.9.1 is almost four years old. Have you considered using something more recent?

Comment: My product wants 4.9.1. So I have to compile against it.
I compiled without -fno-exceptions. Had I compiled with it, compilation would have thrown error.